# How to set PyQt5 QIntValidator's top and bottom?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a line edit like the code below. in 3 different codes I have 2 different problems:

```
self.rnr_id_num_le = QLineEdit()
self.rnr_id_num_le.setValidator(QIntValidator(9999999999, 0))
```

using this I can pnly enter 0 and 1.

and

```
self.rnr_id_num_le = QLineEdit()
self.rnr_id_num_le.setValidator(QIntValidator(0, 9999999999))
```

using this I can only enter 0.

I need it to get a number like this: 5236147891 ( the number of digits are important. If I don't put any numbers in QIntValidator it won't let me enter a number this big)

Based on
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qintvalidator.html#QIntValidator-2
the second one must work; but it doesn't :(

EDIT:

OK, apparently its topest top, if I may, is one digit less than what I need. Do you know another way to validate my QLineEdit, or increase QIntValidator's top?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Please describe the exact error you see.

Comment: by "it doesn't work" I mean I can't enter a number greater than 999999999 but I need to enter 9999999999 ( one more digit )!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [QIntValidator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qintvalidator.html) class only supports signed values in the range `-2147483648` to `2147483647`. If you need values outside this range, use [QDoubleValidator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublevalidator.html), which supports unlimited floating point values.

You can create a simple sub-class of `QDoubleValidator` to tweak the behaviour so that it's more like `QIntValidator`:

```
class BigIntValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator):
    def __init__(self, bottom=float('-inf'), top=float('inf')):
        super(BigIntValidator, self).__init__(bottom, top, 0)
        self.setNotation(QtGui.QDoubleValidator.StandardNotation)

    def validate(self, text, pos):
        if text.endswith('.'):
            return QtGui.QValidator.Invalid, text, pos
        return super(BigIntValidator, self).validate(text, pos)
```